# Android studio use same span multiple times

Tags: java, android

I'm working on the android studio project which requires using same span multiple times in the text. I know the `setspan` method would clear the previous same span. I'm just wondering if there are any approach to solve these kind of problems without using so many different spans.

```
ClickableSpan clk = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(@NonNull View view) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
ss.setSpan(clk, 20, 23, 0);
ss.setSpan(clk, 17, 19, 0);
text.setText(ss);
```